# Reddit search for key and the value in json data

Tags: c#, json, json.net, reddit

i hope someone can help me. i'm a very beginner to json but i try to build a programm that loads all the posts from a subreddit trough the json file. I dont want to save it in a class so creating the classes from json is not an option as i found that not every subreddit has the same structure obviously.

as my example i use the /r/wallpaper https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/hot.json?count=25

That is my current code but i always get a null result to dat2 when searchin in the JObject

```
var json = "";
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    json = client.DownloadString("https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/hot.json?count=25");
    JObject data = JObject.Parse(json);

    string dat2 = data["url"].Value<string>();
}
```

How can i easily search for all value trough a key ? So for example i can get all the thumbnail from each post.
I'm using Json.NET.

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? Where is the code youve given us being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the children and loop through them. Each child has its own url.

Sample code:

```
var json = "";
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    json = client.DownloadString("https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/hot.json?count=25");
    JObject data = JObject.Parse(json);

    var children = data["data"]["children"];
    for (var i = 0; i < children.Count(); i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(children[i]["data"]["url"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you! Thats working perfectly.So i need to access the node where the object is first to search for it in json ?

Comment: That is correct. It's also especially true in your scenario. The program doesn't know if you're looking for one specific url or all urls, and you have to tell it explicitly.